# Python - aiohttp API response content is "StreamReader" type instead of JSON

Tags: python, rest, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm learning the [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/) library with Python 3.10 for making HTTP GET requests, and am practising it with the GitHub v3 REST API. Here's my code for a basic request:

```
# Python Standard Library imports
import asyncio
import sys

# External library imports
import aiohttp

# GitHub API v3 REST endpoint for licenses
GITHUB_URL: str = "https://api.github.com/licenses"
# GitHub query headers
GITHUB_HEADERS: dict = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
}

async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(GITHUB_URL, headers = GITHUB_HEADERS) as GitHub_response:

            print(GitHub_response.content)

if __name__ == "__main__": 

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())

    sys.exit(0)
```

The code runs without errors, but the critical `print(GitHub_response.content` line gives me:

> <StreamReader 2037 bytes eof>

Which is *not what I expected*. And what is a `StreamReader` object anyway???

What I expected was the JSON output which the `curl` command `curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" "https://api.github.com/licenses`
would give me, which looks like:

```
[
  {
    "key": "agpl-3.0",
    "name": "GNU Affero General Public License v3.0",
    "spdx_id": "AGPL-3.0",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/agpl-3.0",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTE="
  },
  {
    "key": "bsd-2-clause",
    "name": "BSD 2-Clause \"Simplified\" License",
    "spdx_id": "BSD-2-Clause",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/bsd-2-clause",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTQ="
  },
.....
```

I tried replacing my `print()` line with `print(GitHub_response.json())`, but that gave me:

```
<coroutine object ClientResponse.json at 0x7f7e452b5e00>
```

So it is still not the JSON I was expecting.

What did I do wrong? And how do I fix my Python code so that I get the actual JSON response *with `aiohttp`*?

**P.S.** I tried doing the above with the Python `requests` library. The content of the response in this case is a `bytes` object which I had to `decode("utf8")` first before using `json.dumps()` from the `json` library to turn it into actual JSON. Not sure if this information is helpful for figuring out what I messed up when using `aiohttp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"content" is an instance of [StreamReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader). This provides a [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) "read" that reads returns the content as string. Insert the following example into your code and you should get the expected result.

```
 x = await GitHub_response.content.read()
 print(x.decode("utf8"))
```

Comment: Aha! For some reason `x` is `bytes` instead of `str` type, so I also added `x.decode("utf8")` to your solution. But other than that it works!
It's unclear to me why "content" is an instance of `StreamReader` instead of something more straightforward that you would get with the `requests` library, but I can live with it. :) Thank you @oosstt!

Answer (score 0):

This can be used:

```
await GitHub_response.text()
```